# split wav file into parts of equal duration, padding with silence if needed

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I need to split wav files into multiple 10-second-long wav files, but each resulting wav file *must* be exactly 10 seconds in length, adding silence if needed – so if a wav file's duration in seconds isn't a multiple of 10, the last wav file should be padded with silence.

I've seen some answers ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336532/split-large-amount-of-wav-files-to-small-parts), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280767/how-do-i-split-an-audio-file-into-multiple), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/525210/splitting-an-audio-file-into-chunks-of-a-specified-length)) which show how to use sox and ffmpeg to split a file into chunks of equal length:

```bsh
$ ffmpeg -i file.wav -f segment -segment_time 10 -c copy out%03d.wav
```

```bsh
$ sox file.wav output-.wav trim 0 10 : newfile : restart
```

but the last file produced by these commands is usually less than 10 seconds long. Is there a way to split a wav file, padding the last file if needed, in the same command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the files, inspect the resulting files (`for i in *wav`), `if (length < 10 seconds)`, pad them.

- To get the wave file length: `sox --info -D file.wav`
- To pad the wave file: https://superuser.com/questions/579008/add-1-second-of-silence-to-audio-through-ffmpeg

Maybe do some calculations :-)